# About finding the rotational volume

Tags: calculus

A closed area of y-axis, $y=\pi, y=x+sin(x)$ is rotated on line y=x. Find the volume of it.

So, I think I have to do an integral looks like this.

$V=\int_{0}^{\sqrt2 \pi} \pi r^2 dt$, where r is the radius of disk and t is a variable on line y=x.

How should I set up the integral and change the variables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that the distance from a point of the curve $y=f(x)$ and the line $y=x$ is $r(x)^2=[f(x)-x]^2/2$.  In this case, $f(x)=x+\sin{x}$.  Then the volume is

$$\pi \int_0^{\pi} dx \, r(x)^2$$

Comment: So you mean that the volume V would be $V=\pi \int_{0}^\pi r(x)^2 dx$

Comment: @SimonComplex: yes, that is exactly what I said.